# "Message as of life or death" - what does "as of" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

In the following sentence, I understand everything but the "as of" part:

> It was the awareness that some speeding messenger from spaces far, far
> beyond the world would presently stand close and touch me, would gaze
> into my little human eyes, would leave its message as of life or
> death, and then depart upon its fearful way again—it was this that
> conveyed the feeling of apprehension that went with me.

The only meaning of "as of" I am aware of relates to time (on, at or since) which does not make sense here (in my opinion).

Comment: The message would be _as_ significant as a life-or-death matter.